# Forma certa de obter uma determinada div

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando descobrir um meio de se acessar uma div via jquery para manipulá-la. Segue o código:

```
<div> <!-- Essa é a div que quero acessar -->
  <div>
    <div>
      <div id="conteudo">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como está mostrado no comentário acima, a div que eu quero acessar é a de raiz mais alta das mostradas aqui. Sei que essas divs ao redor são desnecessárias, mas as vezes alguns frameworks e cms as colocam, e aí me encontro numa situação dessas, tendo que acessar a div que desejo mexer, como está no comentário.

O que eu faço no jquery para acessar é o seguinte:

```
$("#conteudo").parent().parent().parent().css('padding','15px');
```

Como eu posso acessar essa div sem esse código todo? Muitas vezes não consigo tirar essas divs desnecessárias, então queria acessar as divs que desejo de uma maneira mais eficaz (imagina se fossem 10 divs ali, quantos parents eu teria que escrever...)

Comment: você consegue obter o pai da div que quer manipular?

Comment: sim, como mostrei através do parent eu faço isso, mas queria fazer isso de uma maneira melhor, pois se a div estiver envolvida por muitas outras divs, vou ter que usar vários parents

Comment: Vc não entendeu a pergunta, VC consegue saber qual eh o pai, ou que tipo de div existe acima da que você quer manipular?

Comment: ah sim. Olha em alguns casos sim, mas na maioria das vezes não consigo. Esse é um caso que não consigo.

Comment: o problema então é só evitar chamar `.parent()` várias vezes?

Comment: Sim, queria ver se tinha algo melhor a fazer no jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine a função [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) com o seletor [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
$("#conteudo").parents(':eq(2)')
```

Note que a indexação é em 0, então para acessar o 3º nível deve ser usado 2.

Comment: Exatamente isso! Não sabia que essa combinação poderia ser feita!

Answer (score 1):

Coloca um identificador nela um ID ou uma classe e chama ela diretamente

```
<div id="esse"> <!-- Essa é a div que quero acessar -->
  <div>
    <div>
      <div id="conteudo">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Depois faça o `$('#esse').css('padding','15px');` se não for possível mexer nesse div então o Sanção já demonstrou a outra forma.